# how i can resolve javascript error :coin.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inr')

Tags: javascript

```
var car = document.getElementById("Cardano");
var bin = document.getElementById("Binance Coin");
var pol = document.getElementById("Polygon");

var liveprice = {
    "async": true,
    "scroosDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Cdogecoin%2Clitecoin%2CCardano%2CBinanceCoin%2CPolygon%2CYearn.finance%2CXRP%2CTron&vs_currencies=inr",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
}

$.ajax(liveprice).done(function (response){

    car.innerHTML = response.Cardano.inr;
    bin.innerHTML = response.BinanceCoin.inr;
    pol.innerHTML = response.Polygon.inr; 
});
```

Comment: At least one of `response.Cardano` or `response.BinanceCoin` or `response.Polygon` is `undefined`. Without knowing what data you work with, it's impossible to say which one. And if you show the data it should be ***pretty obvious*** which is or isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the property `inr` doesn't exist. You're using it in three places, so you'll need to `console.log` the `response` and find which one it is:

```
car.innerHTML = response.Cardano.inr;
bin.innerHTML = response.BinanceCoin.inr;
pol.innerHTML = response.Polygon.inr;
```

Looking at the response from the api (which doesn't require an api key...) I can see that all of the properties are lower case, so none of your references will work.

I can also see that `Polygon` doesn't exist at all. So your code should be something like:

```
car.innerHTML = response.cardano.inr;
bin.innerHTML = response.binancecoin.inr;
// pol.innerHTML = response.Polygon.inr; Doesn't exist
```

It's always a good practice to make sure the property exists on an object before referencing it. A couple of ways are

```
if ('cardano' in response) {
  car.innerHTML = response.cardano.inr
}
```

Or

```
if (response['cardano'] !== undefined) {
  car.innerHTML = response.cardano.inr
}
```

Or

```
if (Object.keys(response).indexOf('cardano') > -1) {
  car.innerHTML = response.cardano.inr
}
```